# How to achieve the below design using an attributed string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, attributes, uilabel

Need to show the price amount like in the below design. How to achieve the below design using an attributed string in swift? or, is there any other way to achieve this?

[image: attributed String]

Comment: Instead of taking attributed string, it's better to use two labels. One for text and another for amount.

Answer (score 4):

Hey you can try this ..

```
  let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:20)
  let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:10)
  let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "2.449", attributes: [.font:font!])
  attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!,.baselineOffset:5], range: NSRange(location:,length:2))
  labelVarName.attributedText = attString
```

[image: check this image please]